# Where does execution of code continue after a function is called by an event listener?

Tags: javascript, function, event-listener

Edit: I apologize for any confusion. In my code, a loop is running in the script indefinitely until a certain condition is reached. My question is, if an event listener calls a function while this loop is running, after the completion of the function, where would execution continue?

Well, that's pretty much self-explanatory, I guess. After a function is called by an event listener, where does execution of code continue after the function finishes?

Comment: Why would it continue if it was finished?

Comment: Oh sorry. Not where the function continues, where the script continues.

Comment: Again, nowhere. Presumably, by the the time the event handlers start being fired, the script will have already finished.

Comment: Do you mean the event chain? Propagation and bubbling? More so bubbling if after I guess...

Comment: I extended my answer based on the additional info in the question. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an event queue, and whatever is next in that queue gets executed. It could for example be a mouse click event, a window resize or a time-out. If there is nothing on the queue, the container, in which JavaScript runs, will just loop until there is something in the queue to process.

You can read more in MDN's article on ["Concurrency model and Event Loop"](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop):

> A JavaScript runtime contains a message queue, which is a list of messages to be processed. To each message is associated a function. When the stack is empty, a message is taken out of the queue and processed. The processing consists of calling the associated function (and thus creating an initial stack frame). The message processing ends when the stack becomes empty again.

A common way to put something on the message queue is by calling

```
setTimeout(myfunction, 0);
```

As the delay in the second argument is 0, the function *myfunction* will be called once the currently executing code completes, i.e. the call stack becomes empty. Note however, that it could be that some other events were already on the queue. In that case those will still be executed first.

#### What with a long-lasting loop?

You added the following to your question:

> In my code, a loop is running in the script indefinitely until a certain condition is reached. My question is, if an event listener calls a function while this loop is running, after the completion of the function, where would execution continue?

If your loop does not run via asynchronous calls (e.g. with repeated calls to `setTimeout` or with `setInterval`), but looks like this:

```
while (!endingCondition) {
    // do nothing
}
```

then there is no way another (JavaScript) event listener gets called. Such an event will be waiting on the message queue. Only when your current loop and any code after it finishes, will that event be processed and result in the call of the event listener.

So let's look at the following example:

```
var clicked = false;

document.onclick = function() {
    clicked = true;
}

while (!clicked) {};

alert('clicked!');
```

Here one might hope that the `while` loop gets interrupted by a click and shows the alert, but that is not true. The click event will be in the operating system's message queue, but will not be consumed by JavaScript because it always first completes the code it is currently executing. As stated in the above-mentioned [article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoopRun-to-completion):

> whenever a function runs, it cannot be pre-empted and will run entirely before any other code runs.

That *any code* includes all JavaScript code, including code in event handlers.

#### How to write "interruptible" code

The above example can be made to work like this:

```
var clicked = false;

document.onclick = function() {
    clicked = true;
}

function detectClick() {
    if (!clicked) {
        setTimeout(detectClick, 0); // keep repeating
        return;
    }
    alert('clicked!');
    // do something more ...
};
detectClick(); // call for first time
// We get here immediately. Code will end, and events will be processed.
// One of those "events" is a time-out, to which we have set a handler: detectClick.
// At some point a click event will be there as well, triggering the other handler.
```